# Populating cell value using user form textboxes

Tags: vba, excel, userform

Users complete a user form with the value they'd like to replace (a, 34) and what they'd like to replace it with (a, 35).
If the output of the vlookup in (a, 34) is the value from the user form, I'd like it to populate with the value assigned for (a,35) from the user form.  Anytime I run it, I get a "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch"

```
Dim a As Long

a = 5

Range("A5").Activate

Do While Cells(a, 1).Value <> ""

    If Worksheets("PriceMatch").Cells(a, 34).Value = CurrEx.Text Then

        Worksheets("PriceMatch").Cells(a, 35).ClearContents
        Worksheets("PriceMatch").Cells(a, 35).Value = NewEx.Text

    End If

a = a + 1

Loop
a = a + 1
```

Thanks

Comment: What is NewEx.Text - where does it get defined? compile it first. What line is the error on? That should help you figure out

Comment: NewEx.Text and CurrEx.Text is the userform input.  This code is run when the user hits "process" on the userform.  The error happens on the "If Worksheets..." line

Comment: When it errors, go to debug, and in the immediate window, type `?CurrEx.Text` to see if there's text stored in that variable. (Press `CTRL+G` to open Immediate Window). Also, could you post the code where you set `CurrEx`?  And of course, you do have a worksheet called "PriceMatch", yes?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line and add a watch on CurrEx - it probably does not correspond to anything - or you have the wrong property defined. You also might to specifiy the Userform it belongs to.

Comment: When (a, 34) is a vlookup output, it doesn't work.  However, when I replace the vlookup with the output as a text input, it will replace the values.  Any ideas about work arounds?

Comment: Use `.Text`  instead of `.Value` for `Cells(a, 34)`

Comment: Good explanation at http://www.cpearson.com/excel/values.htm